# Can you help me tell if my new out-of-the-box ssd for a Pi4 myNode project is DOA?

Tags: nodes, full-node

Trying to setup a node on a Pi4 with ssd and blockchain appeared to be downloading well. My router said I was gobbling data for 2hrs. Then I received the "Looking for Drive" message. I rebooted once, then shut down once, then rescan which didn't seem to take and then reset . I don't think reindexing is going to do anything.

Would the upgrade from 2.0 to 2.04 help?
or
Can I get any confirmation on here it is a DOA ssd out-of-the-box?
I watched it reboot and the SSD light flashes 3x's and it did this 3x's in a row, waited a few seconds did it one more time, waited a few seconds then blinked constantly for two minutes until I shut it down.

Thank you,

Comment: I strongly disagree with anyone voting to close this question as being a customer relation with a company issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try attaching the SSD to a different computer and run diagnostics on it. If the SSD gave out, upgrading the software would be unlikely to help.